# Rendering Failed with a known bug

Tags: android, class, rendering

I have downloaded a project off of GitHub and then imported it into Android Studio. It seems to work fine, but I keep getting rendering errors on the design view. The designs are just grey screens now and nothing is showing.

Error

> Rendering failed with a known bug. Please try a rebuild.
>   The
>   following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom
>   views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this
>   is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then
>   manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CoordinatorLayout   at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:197)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:189)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) Copy
>   stack to clipboard

I have tried almost every solution put forward to me: Updating, Syncing Gradle, Rebuilding the Project, invalidate caches etc. But nothing seems to work. If anyone could understand the problem better then it would be much appreciated!

As I said, I know people have had this problem before, but none of their solutions are working for me.

Answer (score 10):

Add Base in front of your Style with Base. Cheers to @filol for the thread.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Answer (score 4):

The bug has been reported to google :https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=1&q=230569&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&id=230569